# How can I manipulate DOM using PHP?

Tags: php, ruby, dom

I saw an article here: http://code.lancepollard.com/automatically-publish-posts-to-stumbleupon-with-ruby

I don't know Ruby, but the following lines are pretty self explanatory:

```
  page                         = agent.get("http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=#{url}&title=#{title}")
  form                         = page.forms.first
  form.radiobuttons_with(:name => "sfw").first.check
  page                         = agent.submit(form)
```

I'm guessing Ruby can fetch the webpage, check a checkbox, then submit the form. Is that possible using PHP?

Comment: Since you're going to be learning a new library anyway, you might consider learning ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby code you referenced actually uses a third party library called [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/).

Something similar for PHP is The SimpleTest [Scriptable Browser](http://www.lastcraft.com/browser_documentation.php). It's not as feature rich as Mechanize but can get the job done and it can be used independently of the SimpleTest framework.

Comment: Interesting. I'd never heard of this one.

Answer (score 1):

You probably would want something like:

- http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

PHP's internal support is sufficient, but would be more cumbersome to use than a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. Possibly there is a third-party library that can do it for you. One that might help is PHPQuery to loop over a fetched page and select the form and its values. The submit then would have to be done using Curl or the like...!

More info:

fetching a page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

JQuery for PHP: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Basics for a basic intro

Submitting a form with Curl: http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Comment: Actually `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()` coupled with XPath is an "out of the box" solution. But I would still recommend a third party lib.

Comment: Ruby can't do this out of the box either. The ruby example uses Mechanize, which is not in the standard lib.